# Is there any way to validate the lifetime in DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I'm looking for some way to enforce the checking (runtime, of course) of the proper lifetime registration of dependency-injection services, in .Net Core or higher.

Let's say I have a stateful service like this one:

```
public class MyStatefulService
{
    private object _state;
}
```

However, by mistake, I could register it with the wrong lifetime:

```
services.AddTransient<MyStatefulService>();
```

So, I won't be alerted, but the actual behavior is not what I'd expect: the service is created at every request, and the state won't be preserved.

I wonder if there is a way to reinforce this pattern. For instance, it would be nice if I could decorate the class with an attribute like this:

```
[Singleton]
public class MyStatefulService
{
    private object _state;
}
```

at this point, possibily at startup or at the very first request, the framework should throw if the registration is different than `AddSingleton` (along its overloads).

Similarly, the subject could apply for transient-only services, which shouldn't registered as singletons.

The only solution came in my mind is rather naive, and I don't like so much:

```
//line of principle code
public static class MySingletonChecker
{
    private static HashSet<Type> _set = new HashSet<Type>();

    public static void Validate(Type type)
    {
        if (_set.Contains(type))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            _set.Add(type);
        }
    }
}


public class MyStatefulService
{
    public MyStatefulService()
    {
        MySingletonChecker.Validate(this.GetType());
    }

    private object _state;
}
```

Is there any better solution, hack or anything that helps to prevent errors?

Comment: So you're saying you'll make a mistake when registering the type but not when decorating the type with an attribute?

Comment: I write the service, I know if it needs to be a singleton or not. Is this what you ask for?

Comment: I’m asking “if you write both, why are you likely to not make a mistake when you put the attribute? Why are are you likely to make a mistake when registering the type? Why do you therefore need an attribute (that you will never make a mistake with), to check you didn’t later make a mistake you will make when registering? If you make both things, why will you get it right when you create the class but then 5 minutes later when you register it you will get it wrong?”

Comment: @CaiusJard I'd think like you, if I wouldn't face the problem. First off, the project we're working on uses almost one hundert of services. Secodly, there are several people writing/mantaining those services, but typically only one dealing with registration. Thirdly, many services are designed to be reused in other apps, where the registration cannot be simply "linked". I may even tell you a fourth reason: a service might start as a stateless, then turn to stateful. That's the case of db table adapters, where at a certain point you decide to add a cache.

Comment: How about having ServiceX derive from SingletonService, then later switch it to derive from TransientService, and have genetic helper methods (with restrictions) for your registration that only take objects of particular types, so you get a compiler error when attempting to use the RegisterSingleton helper against a type derived from TransientService?

Comment: Inheritance; a "child" class derives from a "parent" class. Every* class in C# derives from something and many classes derive from something that derives from something (that..)

Comment: @CaiusJard please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to idiot-proof your code, you can provide an extension method to `IServiceCollection` that registers your service exactly the way it should be.

```
public static void AddMyStatefulService(this IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyStatefulService>();
}
```

Then in your services configuration section, the developer would type:

```
services.AddMyStatefulService();
```

Comment: That's another way that most libraries use, that are prepared for usage in Microsoft DI.

Comment: that not prevents to register directly the serveice, but I think it's the best we can have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way like I was pointing out in the comments

Let's have some empty types:

```
public class ScopedService {}
public class TransientService {}
```

Let's have a real service that derives from one of the empty types:

```
public class RealService: ScopedService, IRealService {
  //impl
}
```

And a generic registration method helper:

```
static void MyAddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : ScopedService, TService 
{
    services.AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>();
}
```

Let's register our realservice using the helper:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        MyAddScoped<IRealService, RealService>(services);
    }
```

RealService is a ScopedService - think of this as "how you decorate a service to insist it be added as scoped"

Suppose the developer changes the service to be a transient:

```
class RealService: TransientService, IRealService {
```

Now you get a compiler error from the helper method:

> The type 'YourApplication.RealService' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Startup.MyAddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebApplication1.RealService' to 'WebApplication1.ScopedService'.

Your "one person who looks after registration" can know that the developer is indicating the service is no longer registerable as Scoped and can change it (and the build will be broken until it is changed, which is a good way of preventing accidental release of incorrect code)

Comment: now I understand what you mean: use marker classes. That's a valuable solution, however relies on an helper. An helper/hack would be fine if used by the service implementor (who defines the lifetime of the service). The register should be (possibly) unaware of that. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: All code you write is conceptually a helper.. Write your own registrar and use that instead/hide the AddScoped method.. Write some code that means the service doesn't work properly if the generic AddScoped is used instead of MyAddScoped. Write code like @Slava proposes to check the lifetime vs type at runtime.  *At some point you're going to have to rely on someone to do their job properly* - you can't follow them to the end of their life, doing everything for them. It's why we have rules and code review. In the bounds of your question you did indicate you had reasonable control over them.

Answer (score 0):

To move DI composition to the declaration of a class you could work with some self-made marker interfaces like `IRegisterTransientServiceAs<T>`and add it to your class like this:

```
public class MyStatefulService : IMyStatefulService, IRegisterSingletonServiceAs<IMyStatefulService>
```

Within your composition you have your own extension method that iterates through all loaded types within the application domain, searches for the given generic interface and register them with the declarated lifetime from the given interface.

Maybe this is not real DI, but as you already mentioned, mostly the lifetime of a service is baked into the code of the service itself and it happens very rarely that a specific service will be used in different project with different lifetimes. So IMHO it is okay to bake the desired lifetime into the class itself, instead of making the decision outside.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to validate lifetimes, is by inspecting the entire DI container in the `ConfigureServices` clause.

Each member of a `IServiceCollection` has a `LifeTime` property which gives you the information you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor.lifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceDescriptor_Lifetime